# Looping through thousands of files for big data analysis?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bioinformatics

I'm a beginner in bash scripting, can someone please help me here?

- In a directory (`pamlfiles/`), I had list of files (`*.fa`)

  ```
  OG0018053.fa
  OG0018054.fa
  OG0018055.fa
  ```
- The files look like this:

  ```
  head -n 2 ../pamlfiles/*
  ==> ../pamlfiles/OG0018053.fa <==
  >C.rhe
  ATGAGG------------GTCCTCCTGCTTCTCGGATTGGTGGCTTTTGGCCTGGCTGAC

  ==> ../pamlfiles/OG0018054.fa <==
  >L.fab
  atg---------------------acggacgagatatctctggcgtgtggcatgtcagga

  ==> ../pamlfiles/OG0018055.fa <==
  >A.ven
  ATGAACACTGCCACTCCCACCGAGTTTGACTTCTCTTTCTTGGAAGAGGGCTTCTCCGCC
  ```
- I process them with the following script (`forloop.sh`):

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  for file in ../pamlfiles/*.fa
  do
      filename=$(basename -- "$file")
      gene_name="${filename%%.*}"
      cp codeml_0_opt1_templ.ctl codeml_0.ctl
      sed -i -e "s/GENE/$gene_name/g" codeml_0.ctl
      codeml codeml_0.ctl
  done
  ```

However, when I execute the `forloop.sh`, I get the error

```
Sequence file ../pamlfiles/OG0018055 not found!
```

The `codem1_0_opt1_templ.ctl` looks like this:

```
head codeml_0_opt1_templ.ctl 
seqfile = ../pamlfiles/GENE
outfile = results/GENE_M0.txt
treefile = OG0018055.fa.m.fa.mt.py.nex.treefile
 
noisy = 9
verbose = 0 

runmode = 0
seqtype = 1  
CodonFreq = 2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output of your `codem1` process (whatever that may be), it states that it doesn't find the file `OG0018055` - and this is only logical because the file is actually called `OG0018055.fa`.

In your script, you remove the `.fa` extension from your filename in the line

```
gene_name="${filename%%.*}"
```

to get the gene name. Then, you use `sed` to replace all occurences of the pattern `GENE` with that gene name in the file template. However, that means in your updated `codeml_0.ctl` file, the `seqfile` line looks as follows:

```
seqfile = ../pamlfiles/OG0018055
```

so the `.fa` extension is missing here.

So, just modify your template file to read

```
seqfile = ../pamlfiles/GENE.fa
```

so that the `.fa` filename extension doesn't get lost.